# Traveling Purchaser Problem exact algorithms

Tags: traveling-salesman

how you doing?

Im here to ask for you help. Im writing my bachelor paper as an implementation/review of the TPP algorithms out there. Almost every paper that I read references the Ramesh algorithm, that returns an exact solution for TPP problems, but I just can't find the algorithm, not even a high level description that I could use to implement my own version.

Does someone know how to implement it? I would be grateful with even a high level description.

There's other two approaches out there that I would be grateful to have access: the branch-and-bound algorithm of Singh and Van Oudheusden, and the branch-and-cut algorithm of Laporte. If someone know how to implement or something like that, please share with me.

In these two papers, you can find the actual references:

- https://ir.nctu.edu.tw/bitstream/11536/31784/1/000075284000001.pdf
- https://www.fsa.ulaval.ca/personnel/renaudj/pdf/Recherche/tpp(purchaser)%20COR.pdf

If you don't what's the TPP, please see this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traveling_purchaser_problem before answering

Guys, I know that this is an NP-HARD problem, and that it's always best to use Heuristic Algorithms instead of exact ones for larger instances, but I still want to study the exact ones.

Thanks! Any help is very welcome.

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.  Please provide some background to make this useful for others, including defining what is the TPP and where did you read about the Ramesh algorithm.  Note that asking how to turn pseudocode into code is probably off-topic here; implementation questions are off-topic here.  If you have a specific question about some specific aspect of a particular algorithm, that could be on-topic here.

Comment: When providing references to papers, we prefer that you provide a full citation, including the title of the paper, the authors, and where it was published, so that others with a similar question about that paper can find this page by search, and so that people can still make sense of your question even if those links stop working.